# How to import and build an Ant project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I have an Ant project, but after importing the project my classes are not getting resolved in my IDE and have red icons.

I tried to invalidate its cache and to clone this project repo again, but my issue is still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup SDK properly in your intellij.

You can configure the same via

File --> Project structure --> SDK (Setup java properly or Download if not already there)

File --> Project structure --> Project (Setup java properly)

Comment: Thank You For Your Quick Reply, 
I tried this One also My JDK/SDK is 1.8 Only I have Checked,

Comment: This is My ant project (Servlets + JSP)

Comment: Try 

Right click on pom.xml select Maven -> ReImport.

Comment: Thank You For Your Response,
But this is Ant Project we don't have pom.xml, instead of that we have build.xml,

Comment: In this case you need to [configure module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) in IDE File | [Project Structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html) | Modules dialog for each module. Please see